# Need a book recommendation for the Symmetric Group (Permutations)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, book-recommendation, symmetric-groups

I am looking for a textbook to read about permutations.
Looking for something to cover such topics as:

Representation of permutations (2-line arrays, cycles, bipartite graphs), inverses, involutions, parity of permutations, sign of permutations, transpositions, elementary transpositions, inversions, braid relation, puzzles such as the 15-Puzzle etc.

Comment: It's not a book but expository papers by John Conrad is a good source for some of these things.

Comment: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/